# Change 32-bit PK to BIGINT on 32-bit rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, 32bit-64bit

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app running on 32-bit Ubuntu using MySQL as the backend. The PK for one of my tables is a 32-bit integer and has recently maxed out. I know that you can change the PK from int to BIGINT in MySQL, and MySQL will handle the conversions. My question is will Ruby/Rails be able to handle the new, larger, `id` field since its running on a 32-bit platform?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `INT` or `BIGINT` is not constrained by 32-bit platforms, it's fully supported by both. Although using a 64-bit OS is a good plan for a multitude of reasons, it's not a hard requirement here.

Create a migration to adjust the column type and you should be fine, but be sure to update all columns that reference this particular ID value as well. In other words, follow any `has_many` type associations and be sure they're also using `BIGINT`.